# Searching Through A Very Large MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, search, indexing

I currently have a very small database, but I can expect the database to be quite big after some time *( 1 - 100 million records )* and I want to make sure I always get the top performance.

It might not even matter now, since the database only has a couple of records, *but I want to get it right from the start, and learn something new along the way.*

My application has a search bar, which will search through each product in the database with a same / similar name. It will also allow filters, such as *if price is less than $ 100*. Also, once a product has been found ( or multiple products ), I need to search through the *stores* table to find out which store the product is from.

I started researching different ways for search optimization, and discovered two things:

- *Full Text Search*
- *Indexing Engines*

After doing some reading I came to the realization that Full Text Search will be rather slow, especially in a large database. *That leaves me with using an Indexing Engine.* I haven't yet started work on this, as I want to make sure an indexing engine is what I really need.

For example, these are the tables I use for storing products, and store info:

[image: Product And Store Table]

Would using an *Indexing Engine* be the right choice here?
Also, which one should I use anyway?
I found **Norch**, would it be best suited for this problem?

Comment: You may like a presentation I did some years ago. I didn't test Norch, but I tested Sphinx Search and Solr against the builtin fulltext indexes. [Full Text Search Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql). Another product that has become popular is the [Elastic Stack](https://www.elastic.co/products).

Comment: I will definitely look into it today, once I find some free time. :)

Comment: Although I understand why you are wondering about this question, it isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. This site wants questions about specific coding problems. It is not a place to ask for technology recommendations. Their help center is clear on this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Ah I see, you are right. My apologies. Shall I delete the entire question?

Comment: It will probably get closed for being "off-topic" (at least for Stack Overflow's goals). Also the same question has undoubtedly come up before, so it's probably also a duplicate. But I am not sure that I have a suggestion for another internet site to look for recommendations. One possibility is https://alternativeto.net/software/apache-solr/

Comment: Can't discuss performance and schemas without seeing the `SELECTs`.

Comment: `FULLTEXT` is very fast _when it is applicable_.

Comment: Define what you mean by "similar name".  This is virtually impossible to optimize, so I suggest you abandon that requirement.